# Android Studio fails refactoring "read-only" kapt generated code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

Working with Kotlin and Dagger I find that if I try to use Android Studio's Refactoring feature to change, e.g., the name of a class that is referenced in the code that kapt autogenerates for Dagger (in $buildDir/generated/source/kapt), that the refactor fails because the autogenerated code is "read-only".

Deleting the build directory is a heavy-handed workaround.  Is there a setting or something that will prevent the problem?

Comment: filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65506817

Comment: Other people have complained about this as well.  The P1/S1 bug tracking issue is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65032914 .  My bug was closed into it.